# Magento and Wordpress Joint. How do i edit a page manually or the CSS?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, magento

I am having problems trying to figure out how exactly i can edit a simple page of the website. I didn't initially create it so i am given the task of trying to understand someones code. So the problem is... i am trying to change the simple font colour on the front home page, but i cannot even find the CSS file on magento or Wordpress so i'm kind of confused. I want to change the white font colour to black.

Do i just log in with FTP and edit the pages manually on there? Please give me some information on how i can go about editing any pages at all.

Comment: What's the link to the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

## Wordpress

Wordpress have **/wp-content/themes/** for a directory which stores all instaled themes (downloaded or created by you). You can edit everything of a theme there. The default stylesheet file in wp's **/wp-content/themes/[yourtheme]/style.css**. Attention: this CSS file can [import](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcssatimport.htm) another from somewhere else.

## Finding the style

You can find the ids and classes statements just positioning the mouse over the element that you want to discover what is influencing it, right button click and select Inspect Element if in Chrome or Mozilla. An add-on to help is Web Developer.

#### Possibly useful links: http://ithemes.com/tutorials/ ; http://mcbuzz.wordpress.com/wordpress-tutorials-complete-list/ ; http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/ ; http://line25.com/articles/15-tutorials-to-help-you-build-wordpress-themes

#### Web developer

[**Mozilla**](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/web-developer/) | [**Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm)

**@edit** Yes, you can edit via FPT or SSH connection ;P

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress you should check in settings->reading what the front page is set to and css changes can be done in the theme folder `wp-content/themes/theme_name/` and for magento the css is usually in `/skin/frontend/package/theme/css`. or somewhere close depending on the template.